# PHP Need Fresh Eyes

Tags: php

I have a php script that is throwing this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in I have checked and rechecked the code I can not find any missing semicolons or brackets. Pleases give it a look maybe you can see what I have missed.

```
    <?php
    require_once('./session.php');
    require_once('./fileloader.php');
    $mysqli = new mysqli("$ip", "$username", "$password", "$db");
    $mysqlil = new mysqli("$ipl", "$usernamel", "$passwordl", "$dbl");
    // start of post
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $pool = $_POST["pool"];
    $dns = $_POST["dns"];
    $site = $_POST["site"];
    $port = $_POST["port"];
    // end of post

    // start of data sanitize and existence check
 if (empty($name)){
    // If input feild is empty it goes back to the fourm and informs the user
    $_SESSION['exitcodev2'] = 'name';
    header('Location: adddhcp.php');
    exit;
} elseif(empty($pool)){
    // If input feild is empty it goes back to the fourm and informs the user
    $_SESSION['exitcodev2'] = 'pool';
     header('Location: adddhcp.php');
    exit;
}elseif(empty($dns)){
    // If input feild is empty it goes back to the fourm and informs the user
    $_SESSION['exitcodev2'] = 'dns';
     header('Location: adddhcp.php');
    exit;
}elseif(empty($site)){
    // If input feild is empty it goes back to the fourm and informs the user
    $_SESSION['exitcodev2'] = 'site';
     header('Location: adddhcp.php');
    exit;
}elseif(empty($port)){
    // If input feild is empty it goes back to the fourm and informs the user
    $_SESSION['exitcodev2'] = 'con';
     header('Location: adddhcp.php');
    exit;
}else{
    //resets the code
     $_SESSION['exitcodev2'] = '';
}


$name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($name);
$pool = $mysqli->real_escape_string($pool);
$dns = $mysqli->real_escape_string($dns);
$site = $mysqli->real_escape_string($site);
$portid = $mysqli->real_escape_string($port);

// end of data sanitize and existence check
// start of data entry
if ($result3 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `device_ports` WHERE `use` = 'mgmt' and `devices_iddevices` = '$site'")) {
                /* fetch associative array */
                 while ($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
                     $portidm= $row3["port id"];
                     }
                     }
if ($resultl = $mysqlil->query("SELECT * FROM `ipv4_addresses` WHERE `port_id` = '$portidm'")) {
                /* fetch associative array */
                 while ($rowl = $resultl->fetch_assoc()) {
                     $routerip= $rowl["ipv4_address"];
                     }
                     }
if ($resultl = $mysqlil->query("SELECT * FROM `ipv4_addresses` WHERE `port_id` = '$portid'")) {
                /* fetch associative array */
                 while ($rowl = $resultl->fetch_assoc()) {
                     $defaultrouter= $rowl["ipv4_address"];
                     $ipv4network = $rowl["ipv4_network_id"];
                 }
                 }
if ($resultl = $mysqlil->query("SELECT * FROM `ipv4_networks` WHERE `ipv4_network_id` = '$ipv4network'")) {
                /* fetch associative array */
                 while ($rowl = $resultl->fetch_assoc()) {
                     $subnet= $rowl["ipv4_network"];
                     }
                     }
$long = ip2long($defaultrouter);
$start = $long +1;
$start =long2ip($start);
$end = $long + $pool + 1;
$end = long2ip($end);

$ssh = new Net_SSH2("$routerip");
if (!$ssh->login("$rname", "$rpass")) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

$ssh->exec("/opt/vyatta/sbin/vyatta-cfg-cmd-wrapper begin\n
/opt/vyatta/sbin/vyatta-cfg-cmd-wrapper set service dhcp-server shared-network-name $name authoritative disable\n
/opt/vyatta/sbin/vyatta-cfg-cmd-wrapper set service dhcp-server shared-network-name $name subnet $subnet default-router $defaultrouter\n
/opt/vyatta/sbin/vyatta-cfg-cmd-wrapper set service dhcp-server shared-network-name $name subnet $subnet dns-server $dns\n
/opt/vyatta/sbin/vyatta-cfg-cmd-wrapper set service dhcp-server shared-network-name $name subnet $subnet lease 86400\n
/opt/vyatta/sbin/vyatta-cfg-cmd-wrapper set service dhcp-server shared-network-name $name subnet $subnet start $start stop $end\n
/opt/vyatta/sbin/vyatta-cfg-cmd-wrapper commit\n
/opt/vyatta/sbin/vyatta-cfg-cmd-wrapper save\n");

if ($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `$db`.`dhcp_servers` (`idDHCP_Servers`,
                   `DNS`, `Range_Start`, `Range_Stop`, `subnet`, `name`,
                   `device_ports_iddevice_ports`) VALUES
                   (NULL, '$dns', '$start', '$end', '$subnet', '$name', '$portid');") === TRUE) {
//nothing 
} else{
    echo'Something went wrong with the database please contact your webmaster';
        exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: In which file and on which line do you get the error?

Comment: The above code doesn't have any syntax error

Comment: There's no error in this file.

Comment: Everything looks good though.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I restarted Apache and it worked. Not sure what the issue was.

Comment: could it be that PHP has opcache enabled so it did not update right away?